# inkcanvas inside scatterview

Tags: scatterview, inkcanvas

I want to detect gestures on my scatterview (so not on elements inside the scatterview). I found that the surfaceInkCanvas has some gesture possibilities but how can I put a kind of invisible surfaceinkcanvas inside my scatterview?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

SurfaceInkCanvas won't actually do any gesture recognition.  There are some gesture related events exposed on it but those are just there because they are on the base class - they aren't actually used